# Using Python decorators to retry request

Tags: python, python-requests

I have multiple functions in my script which does a REST API api requests.As i need to handle the error scenarios i have put a retry mechanism as below.

```
no_of_retries = 3
def check_status():
    for i in range(0,no_of_retries):
        url = "http://something/something"
        try:
            result = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(COMMON_USERNAME, COMMON_PASSWORD)).json()
            if 'error' not in result:
                return result
            else:
                continue
        except Exception as e:
            continue
    return None
```

I have several different methods which does similar operation. How can we do it better way to avoid duplication may be using decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using decorators, the probably better solution is to move the request to its own function, arriving at a structure similar to this:

```
no_of_retries = 3

def make_request(url):
    for i in range(0,no_of_retries):
        try:
            result = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(COMMON_USERNAME, COMMON_PASSWORD)).json()
            if 'error' not in result:
                return result
            else:
                continue
        except Exception as e:
            continue
    return result

def check_status():
    result = make_request("http://something/status")

def load_file():
    result = make_request("http://something/file")
```

This way, you avoid duplicate code while encapsulating the request. If you were to use a decorator, you would need to wrap the whole `load_file()` method which would prevent you from further processing the request's result within this function.

Answer (score 33):

You can use a decorator like this and handle your own exception.

```
def retry(times, exceptions):
    """
    Retry Decorator
    Retries the wrapped function/method `times` times if the exceptions listed
    in ``exceptions`` are thrown
    :param times: The number of times to repeat the wrapped function/method
    :type times: Int
    :param Exceptions: Lists of exceptions that trigger a retry attempt
    :type Exceptions: Tuple of Exceptions
    """
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(*args, **kwargs):
            attempt = 0
            while attempt < times:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except exceptions:
                    print(
                        'Exception thrown when attempting to run %s, attempt '
                        '%d of %d' % (func, attempt, times)
                    )
                    attempt += 1
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return newfn
    return decorator

@retry(times=3, exceptions=(ValueError, TypeError))
def foo1():
    print('Some code here ....')
    print('Oh no, we have exception')
    raise ValueError('Some error')

foo1()
```

Comment: I started writing my own and then realized it must have been done a million times before.  This was perfect except I added a timeout param with a time.sleep() when attempt=times before returning the func().  Thanks!

Answer (score 28):

if you do not mind installing a library you could use the [`tenacity`](https://pypi.org/project/tenacity/) ([github.com/jd/tenacity](https://github.com/jd/tenacity)) module. one of their examples:

```
import random
from tenacity import retry, stop_after_attempt

# @retry  # retry forever
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3))
def do_something_unreliable():
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise IOError("Broken sauce, everything is hosed!!!111one")
    else:
        return "Awesome sauce!"

print(do_something_unreliable())
```

this also allows you to specify the number of tries or seconds you want to keep retrying.

for your case this might look something like this (not tested!):

```
@retry(stop=stop_after_attempt(3))
def retry_get():
    result = requests.get(
            url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(COMMON_USERNAME, COMMON_PASSWORD)).json()
    if 'error' not in result:
        raise RequestException(result)
```

Answer (score 12):

The third-party [retry module](https://pypi.org/project/retry/) is an option for this purpose. You can also pass the list of exceptions to retry for, number of retries, delays, maximum delay, exponential back-off, etc.

```
$ pip install retry
```

Example usage:

```
from retry import retry

@retry(ZeroDivisionError, tries=3, delay=2)
def make_trouble():
    '''Retry on ZeroDivisionError, raise error after 3 attempts, sleep 2 seconds between attempts.'''
```

Comment: It is now widely accepted? At 2022-09 there are no updates in 6 years and the project looks to be abandoned.

Comment: @ZiurOlpa, rather than calling it abandoned or obsolete, I would like to call it Complete. There is no update because one isn't needed apparently.

Comment: @MohitC New and unhandled issues tell a different story.

Comment: If you check Github stars, the big libraries seem to be [`tenacity`](https://github.com/jd/tenacity) (4.9k stars, last updated in 2023) and [`backoff`](https://github.com/litl/backoff) (2.2k stars, last updated in 2023), in contrast to [`retrying`](https://github.com/rholder/retrying)  (1.9k stars, last updated in 2016) and [`retry`](https://github.com/invl/retry) (621 stars, last updated in 2016).

Answer (score 9):

## Production level example

```py
import logging
import time
import functools
import traceback

LOG_FORMAT = "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(pathname)s - %(funcName)s - %(lineno)d -msg: %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format=LOG_FORMAT)


def retry(retry_num, retry_sleep_sec):
    """
    retry help decorator.
    :param retry_num: the retry num; retry sleep sec
    :return: decorator
    """
    def decorator(func):
        """decorator"""
        # preserve information about the original function, or the func name will be "wrapper" not "func"
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            """wrapper"""
            for attempt in range(retry_num):
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)  # should return the raw function's return value
                except Exception as err:   # pylint: disable=broad-except
                    logging.error(err)
                    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
                    time.sleep(retry_sleep_sec)
                logging.error("Trying attempt %s of %s.", attempt + 1, retry_num)
            logging.error("func %s retry failed", func)
            raise Exception('Exceed max retry num: {} failed'.format(retry_num))

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

## usage

```py
# this means try your function 5 times, each time sleep 60 seconds
@retry(5, 60)
def your_func():
    pass
```

---

Formal reference: https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/

Comment: learn more about decorators: [realpython](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using the [retry](https://github.com/invl/retry) library like @MohitC mentioned. However, if you're restricted to import 3rd party libraries like I was, you're welcome to try my version:

---

```py
import time

def retry(tries= -1, delay=0, max_delay=None, backoff=1, exceptions=Exception, log=False):
    """Retry Decorator with arguments
    Args:
        tries (int): The maximum number of attempts. Defaults to -1 (infinite)
        delay (int, optional): Delay between attempts (seconds). Defaults to 0
        max_delay (int, optional): The maximum value of delay (seconds). Defaults to None (Unlimited)
        backoff (int, optional): Multiplier applied to delay between attempts (seconds). Defaults to 1 (No backoff)
        exceptions (tuple, optional): Types of exceptions to catch. Defaults to Exception (all)
        log (bool, optional): Print debug logs. Defaults to False
    """
    def retry_decorator(func):
        def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal tries, delay, max_delay, backoff, exceptions, log
            while tries:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except exceptions:
                    tries -= 1

                    # Reached to maximum tries
                    if not tries:
                        raise
                    
                    # Log the retry logs for the given function
                    if log:
                        print(f"Retrying {func.__name__} in {delay} seconds")

                    # Apply delay between requests
                    time.sleep(delay)

                    # Adjust the next delay according to backoff
                    delay *= backoff

                    # Adjust maximum delay duration
                    if max_delay is not None:
                        delay = min(delay, max_delay)

        return retry_wrapper
    return retry_decorator
```

### Example Uses:

Simple:

```py
    @retry(10, delay=5)
    def do_something(params):
        # Example func to retry
        pass
```

Advanced:

```py
    @retry(10, delay=1, backoff=2, max_delay=10, exceptions=(TimeoutError), log=True)
    def do_something(params):
        # Example func to retry only for TimeoutErrors
        pass
```

Comment: Best [Python decorator explanation video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjHpMCIvwsY&ab_channel=PyCon2019) I found so far

Answer (score 1):

I have created a custom retry function. The function will retry if the first number is less than the second.

**CODE:**

```
import time

# CUSTOM EXCEPTION
class custom_error(Exception):
    pass


# RETRY FUNCTION.
def retry(func, retries=3):
    print(func)

    def retry_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        print(args)
        n = args[0]
        u = args[1]
        print(n, u)

        attempts = 0
        while attempts < retries:
            try:
                if n > u:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    raise custom_error
            except custom_error:
                print("error")
                time.sleep(2)
                attempts += 1

    return retry_wrapper


@retry
def akash(a, b):
    c = a / b
    return c


# CALLING THE FUNCTION
a = akash(1, 2)
print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<function akash at 0x00000187C3A66B00>
(1, 2)
1 2
error
error
error
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `functools` on top of mrkiril's answer:

```
from functools import wraps, partial

def retry(f=None, times=10):
    if f is None:
        return partial(retry, times=times)

    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        attempt = 0
        while attempt < times:
            try:
                return f(*args, **kwargs)
            except:
                print(f"{f.__name__}, attempt {attempt} of {times}")
                attempt += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap
```

Then, wrap your function like the following:

```
import random

@retry
def foo():
    if random.randint(0, 5) != 0:
        raise Exception
```