# Python mock function that returns dictionary multiple times

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-mock

#### Background

I have a function `my_func` that gets a dictionary from another function `get_dict` and modifies it. On failure, `my_func` gets retried until it succeeds or called a specified number of times. What complicates this is that the dictionary must have exactly one key-value pair, otherwise other exceptions are raised. Here is a stripped down example of the function:

```
class MyClass:

    def get_dict(self):
        # Returns a dict

    @retry(3) # Decorator that controls the error handling and retries
    def my_func(self):
        a_dict = self.get_dict()

        if len(a_dict) == 0:
            raise WrongException

        if len(a_dict) > 1:
            raise OtherWrongException

        key, value = a_dict.popitem() # Key-value pair is popped off the dict

        # Do stuff

        raise MyException
```

#### Problem

I'm trying to unit test the failure case of `my_func`, specifically that `MyException` gets correctly raised after all retries fail. To do this, I mocked the output of `get_dict`, but because I pop key-value pairs, the original dict is modified. In the real case, `get_dict` will "refresh" the dict with a new one every time it is called, but the mock dict does not.

This was my unit test attempt:

```
import MyClass
from unittest import mock, TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(MyClass, "get_dict")
    def test_my_func(self, mock_dict):
        my_class = MyClass()
        mock_dict.return_value = {"key": "value"}

        self.assertRaises(MyException, my_class.my_func)
```

Instead of the test passing with `MyException` getting raised, the mocked dictionary return value is modified by the function call and not refreshed for the retry attempts, causing the test to fail when the function raises `WrongException`.

I have considered setting the `side_effect` of the mock instead of the return value and just passing a list of dictionaries equal to the number of retry attempts, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

How can I mock the return value of `get_dict` so that it returns the unmodified dict every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning a mutable object as return value to the mock object:

```
mock.patch.object(return_value=...)
```

You could patch the function with a lambda that returns the mutable object:

```
mock.patch.object(new=lambda ...)
```

Also, the `retry` decorator should probably be tested independently.

(`retry` decorator yanked and adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030200/20103413))

###### myclass.py

```
def retry(times, exceptions):
    """
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64030200/20103413
    Retry Decorator
    Retries the wrapped function/method `times` times if the exceptions listed
    in ``exceptions`` are thrown
    :param times: The number of times to repeat the wrapped function/method
    :type times: Int
    :param Exceptions: Lists of exceptions that trigger a retry attempt
    :type Exceptions: Tuple of Exceptions
    """
    def decorator(func):
        def newfn(*args, **kwargs):
            attempt = 1
            while attempt <= times:
                try:
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                except exceptions as exc:
                    print(
                        '%s thrown when attempting to run %s, attempt '
                        '%d of %d' % (type(exc), func, attempt, times)
                    )
                    attempt += 1
            raise TooManyRetriesException('Maximum attempts exceeded. Terminating retry sequence.')
        return newfn
    return decorator


class MissingItemsException(Exception):
    pass

class TooManyItemsException(Exception):
    pass

class TooManyRetriesException(Exception):
    pass


class MyClass:

    def get_dict(self):
        # Returns a dict
        pass

    @retry(3, (RuntimeError,)) # Decorator that controls the error handling and retries
    def my_func(self):
        a_dict = self.get_dict()

        if len(a_dict) == 0:
            raise MissingItemsException

        if len(a_dict) > 1:
            raise TooManyItemsException

        key, value = a_dict.popitem() # Key-value pair is popped off the dict

        # Do stuff
```

###### test_myclass.py

```
from myclass import MyClass, TooManyRetriesException, TooManyItemsException, MissingItemsException
from unittest import mock, TestCase

class MyTest(TestCase):

    @mock.patch.object(MyClass, "get_dict", new=lambda self: {"key": "value"})
    def test_my_func_success(self):
        my_class = MyClass()

    @mock.patch.object(MyClass, "get_dict", new=lambda self: {})
    def test_my_func_missing_items(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertRaises(MissingItemsException, my_class.my_func)

    @mock.patch.object(MyClass, "get_dict", new=lambda self: {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"})
    def test_my_func_too_many_items(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        self.assertRaises(TooManyItemsException, my_class.my_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified example of how I would *in general* mock-up a method so that on successive calls it returns different values. You would, of course, modify `mocked_get_dict` to return whatever you needed and `my_func` to test approproately.

```py
from unittest import mock

def retry(cnt):
    def retry_internal(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal cnt
            while cnt:
                try:
                    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e, end='')
                    cnt -= 1
                    if (cnt):
                        print(' retrying...')
                    else:
                        print()
                else:
                    return result
        return wrapper
    return retry_internal

class MyClass:

    def get_dict(self):
        # Returns a dict
        return {}

    @retry(3)
    def my_func(self):
        d = self.get_dict()
        if not 'x' in d:
            raise ValueError(f'"x" key is missing: {d}')
        print(d)

mock_call_number = -1
mock_return_values = [
    {'a': 1},
    {'b': 2},
    {'x': 3}
]

def mocked_get_dict(self):
    global mock_call_number

    mock_call_number += 1
    if mock_call_number >= len(mock_return_values):
        raise 'Not enough mocked values.'
    return mock_return_values[mock_call_number]

class MyTest:
    @mock.patch.object(MyClass, 'get_dict', mocked_get_dict)
    def test_my_func(self):
        my_class = MyClass()
        my_class.my_func()

MyTest().test_my_func()
```

Prints:

```None
"x" key is missing: {'a': 1} retrying...
"x" key is missing: {'b': 2} retrying...
{'x': 3}
```

Comment: How is this any different than just using side_effects? Also doesn't really answer my question, as I already mentioned that I could just pass in a list of return values through side effects.